# IAR CodeCoverage exclude specific files from coverage

Tags: code-coverage, iar

I have created a small script that uploads the code to the MSP430 device and generates a code coverage report.

```
"<IAR Path>\common\bin\cspybat" -f "<ProjPath>\settings\Tests.Debug.general.xcl" --debug_file=<ProjPath>\Debug\Exe\Tests.d43 "--plugin=<IAR Path>\common\plugins\CodeCoverage\CodeCoverage.dll" --code_coverage_file C:\CodeCoverageReport.log  --backend -f "<ProjPath>\settings\Tests.Debug.driver.xcl"
```

Everything is working fine except the report includes every function from every single file included in the project. Is there a way to exclude some sources (or whole directories) or specify for which sources the report is generated for?

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @mjs unfortunately no. We ended up having x86 tests with lcov and mocked registers.